# Load JSON into multiprocessing.managers.DictProxy object

Tags: python, json, dictionary, multiprocessing

I am trying to load a JSON object into a `DictProxy` object, but am not seeing an "easy" way.  I can load the JSON into a dictionary easy enough, but if I try to copy this `dict` into a `DictProxy`, it stays as a `dict` (which makes sense the way I am doing it).  I could create an empty `DictProxy`, then build a function that loops through my `dict` and populates the `DictProxy`, but I feel like this should be unnecessary.  I also can't really find much documentation on `DictProxy`, so I am not really sure what features it shares (or doesn't share) with `dict`.  Is there a clean way to do this, or should I build the function that loops through the `dict` and builds the `DictProxy`?

Code:

```
import multiprocessing
import json

def main():
    with open(r"c:\path\to\my.json") as js:
        my_dict = json.load(js)    
    print type(my_dict) # <type 'dict'>

    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    my_dict_proxy = manager.dict()
    print type(my_dict_proxy) # <class 'multiprocessing.managers.DictProxy'>

    my_dict_proxy = my_dict
    print type(my_dict_proxy) # <type 'dict'>

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DictProxy` provides an `update()` method.  You should be able to do this:

```
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
my_dict_proxy = manager.dict()
my_dict_proxy.update(my_dict)
```

Comment: Well I feel dumb now.  That worked perfectly, thanks!